# Subscribing and unsubscribing from a method instead of a delegate?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, delegates, event-handling

I know there are times you need to keep track of a delegate so that it can be unsubscribed properly:

```
private EventHandler _handler;

public void Foo()
{
    if (_handler != null)
    {
        Something.SomeEvent -= _handler; // Unsubscribe old event
    }

    _handler = delegate(object sender, EventArgs args) { };;
    Something.SomeEvent += _handler;
}
```

---

But, is that still necessary if you use a method instead?

```
public void CustomMethod(object sender, EventArgs args) { ... }

public void Foo()
{
    // Not sure how to unsubscribe only if it wasn't subscribed first?
    if (some way to check)
    {
        Something.SomeEvent -= CustomMethod;
    }

    Something.SomeEvent += CustomMethod;
}
```

Comment: Use SomeEvent.GetInvocationList() method to check which methods are subscribed to your event

Comment: I'll let experts have the final say, but I see little difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not necessary. If you are always subscribing/unsubscribing the same method (in the form of a delegate), then you don't need to track the actual delegate instance that was subscribed. The new delegate instances (implicitly created for you by the C# compiler in the += and -= operations) are correctly identified as identical, so that the -= operation removes the delegate that was added in the += operation.

In other words, equality for the Delegate class is not just "reference equality". Two completely different Delegate instances that have the same invocation list are considered equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna check if a specific method subscribed or not you can use [`GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist(v=vs.110).aspx) and then Linq:

```
var mInfo = typeof(SomeType).GetMethod("CustomMethod");

if(Something.SomeEvent.GetInvocationList().Any(x => x.Method == mInfo))
{

}
```